# How to use tidyr::separate to get only the first element

Tags: r, string, tidyr

Let's suppose that I would like to separate a column to three different columns values split by the slash.

```
df2 <- data.frame(player=c('A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C'),
                     year=c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2),
                     stats=c('22/2/3', '29/3/4', '18/6/7', '11/1/2', '12/1/1', '19/2/4'))
```

I would use the following code

```
separate(df, col=stats, into=c('points', 'assists', 'steals'), sep='/')
```

But if I would like keep just the first element in one single column and the other two separated? I mean something like (example for just the first row):

```
col1   col2

22     2/3
```

How should I change the following code?

```
separate(df2, col=stats, into=c('points', 'assist'), sep='/')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `separate` function has an `extra=` parameter to control what happens when you find more than you are extracting. Use `extra="merge"` here to collapse the values

```
separate(df2, col=stats, into=c('points', 'assist'), sep='/', extra="merge")
#   player year points assist
# 1      A    1     22    2/3
# 2      A    2     29    3/4
# 3      B    1     18    6/7
# 4      B    2     11    1/2
# 5      C    1     12    1/1
# 6      C    2     19    2/4
```

Answer (score 2):

There is also the relatively new `tidyr::separate_wider_delim`. The key here is in MrFlick's answer - the argument `extra = "merge"`, here as `too_many = "merge"`

```
library(tidyr)

df2 |> 
    separate_wider_delim(stats,
                         names = c("points", "assists_steals"),
                         delim = "/",
                         too_many = "merge"
                         )

# A tibble: 6 × 4
  player  year points assists_steals
  <chr>  <dbl> <chr>  <chr>         
1 A          1 22     2/3           
2 A          2 29     3/4           
3 B          1 18     6/7           
4 B          2 11     1/2           
5 C          1 12     1/1           
6 C          2 19     2/4
```

We can also use `separate_wider_regex`. In this function, we specify a special "patterns" argument, a vector of patterns. Named patterns are extracted into corresponding new columns, and unnamed patters are discarded.

```
df2 |> 
    separate_wider_regex(cols = stats,
                         patterns = c(points = "\\d+",
                                      "/",
                                      assists_steals = ".*"
                                      )
                        )
```